# Vertically fixed slider to content below

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an image slider on top of my website. It's here on my hosting [page with top slider](http://sun8.hol.es/ataora/)

I need to fix this slider vertically, so bottom content will scroll above my slider. When slider will stay like fixed block.
I have the same example with image, this is the same page but instead of slider here is block with background image, and fixed background-attachment [the same page with background image on top](http://ataora.infodaymedia.com/HTML/index.html)

So in second link you can see effect what I want to apply with slider. Is it possible? I can't find way.

Comment: You mean you want a parallax effect?

Comment: Looks like parallax effect, but i can't find instrument's to apply in this situation. Parallax will be here? and what instrument I need to use? What will be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your current css and it should have the effect you're seeking.

```
.slider-bg {
 position: relative;
 z-index: -1;
 height: 502px;
}

.flexslider {
 position: fixed;
}
```

You need to set color for your `.container` as well or create a new class/id name for all your sections (ie your .container) and apply a background color to it.

**Updated**

Since your slider have a buttons, setting its z-index to -1 would make the buttons unclickable, you need to set you `.slider-bg` z-index to 1 and your

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just tried and looks like it's working. But i didn't see styling block's like in your example. Can you just a little explain what is going on here? In your code. I understood about new block's to set colors, thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain the code.  Mainly, the purposoe for position: relative in the slider-bg class.

Comment: To use z-index, the element must have a position.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want Carousel. The Carousel plugin is a component for cycling through elements, like a carousel (slideshow).

Tip: Plugins can be included individually (using Bootstrap's individual "carousel.js" file), or all at once (using "bootstrap.js" or "bootstrap.min.js").

Sample Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators 
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>-->

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls 
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>-->
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want more information in simplified way please visit [this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)

Comment: This is incorrect, he is asking for a parallax effect

Comment: I use flex slider and i think for slider it's enough. Like you can see in comment above I need something like parallax effect with my slider. Also I use materializecss so bootstrap is not correct here

Comment: Ohh ok, for that purpose also you can use bootstrap. Do you know bootstrap ?